# How to get my start and stop button to work using javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, button, google-chrome-extension, html-table

Hello I am currently a create a google chrome extension with a start and stop button that logs every url that has been visited. My start/ stop button function algorithm is not working fully. The goal is When the start button is clicked I want it to continuously add a row to my html table(every time a url is visited)- which the addRow function basically does. And to not add any more rows when the stop button has been clicked.

Current code:

**popup.js**

```
//Start and Stop buttons for logging
const btnStart = document.getElementById("click-start");
const btnStop = document.getElementById("click-stop");


//attempt to get start/stop logging buttons to work--underwork
function Logger(isLogging) {
    console.log(isLogging)
        
        if (isLogging){
        
        btnStart.style.display= "block";
        btnStop.style.display= "none";
        
        
        
    } else {
        
        btnStart.style.display= "none";
        btnStop.style.display= "block";
    }
}
addRow();

//button to start/stop logging
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    btnStart.addEventListener("click", function() {Logger(true)}); 
    btnStop.addEventListener("click", function() {Logger(false)});
});


//using storage API to save data for last btn pressed--underwork
chrome.storage.local.set({key: Logger()}, function() {
    console.log('value is set to  ' + Logger());
});

chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], function(result) {
    console.log('value currently is ' + result.key);
});
    


//function to append row to HTML table 
function addRow() {
        //perhaps need an for loop for every page visited 
  
    
    const bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()    
    Object.keys(bg.get).forEach(function (url) {
    
    //get html table
        // Append product to the table
    var table = document.getElementById("tbodyID");
        
            
            var arr = url.split("/");
            var protocoll = arr[0] + "//" + arr[2];
        
            //inputed data --
            browser= "Google Chrome"; 
            protocol = protocoll;
            downloads = "example";
            description = "example";
            time = Date.now();

        
        //put dates in array and replace it and have var as myDate
    // add new row to the table
                  //1 = in the top 
                  //table.rows.length = the end
                  //table.rows.length/2+1 = the center 

            var newRow = table.insertRow(0);
            
            console.log(table.rows.length)
                  
                  // add cells to the row
                  var browserCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
                  var timeCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
                  var urlCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
                  var protocolCell = newRow.insertCell(3);
                  var downloadsCell = newRow.insertCell(4);
                  var descCell = newRow.insertCell(5);
                  
                  // add the data to the cells
                  
                  urlCell.innerHTML = `${url}`; 
                  timeCell.innerHTML = time;
                    browserCell.innerHTML = browser;
                    descCell.innerHTML = description;
                    protocolCell.innerHTML = protocol;
                    downloadsCell.innerHTML = downloads;
                  console.log("works");
     }) 
            }
```

**popup.html**

```
<!--Start button of logging-->
    <button class="button button1" id="click-start" >
    <u> Start Logging </u>
    </button>
    
    <!--Stop button of logging-->
    <button class="button button2" id="click-stop">
    <u> Stop Logging </u>
    </button>
    
    <table class="roundedCorners" id = "tableID" border="1">
        <thead>
        <!--Example table header row with the user, url visited, and time they visited the url etc-->
            <tr>
      <!--categories-->
                <th>Browser</th>
                <th>Timestamp</th>
                <th>URL</th>
                <th>Protocol</th> 
                <th>Downloaded File Names</th> 
                <th>Description</th>
      
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id= "tbodyID">
           
         
            
        </tbody>
     <!--Goal is to append to this table-->
     
    
    </table>
```

Comment: So what seems to be the issue with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems it could be long answer so I only answered with draft.

First will explain how to log after clicking start logging. With only popup.js it will not be easy to let js keep logging. There is a reason, which is page action(popup.js) is only alive when page window is activated. When clicking page action button(extension plugin button), then popup.js is started to activate. When the popup.html is closed then js is stoped. When web page is turned to other page then popup.html is closed. To keep logging content.js is needed.

content.js is executed on current tab on certain url. If url match condition is <all_url> on manifest.json then on every web page the js file is executed. If logging function is used then contents.js should get the function. `addRow()` should be in contents.js file. But start and stop button should be used then popup.js should send message by using `runtime.sendMessage()`. It's different to people, for me I send message to background from content.js as to if condition flag.  Reference here :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage

So on contents.js file `addRow()` needed to execute by `runtime.onMessage`. So when popup.js send message to contents.js with a flag then contents.js decides to start or stop logging. Like below:

on `popup.html`(start/stop) -> content.js(logging)

The codes I added below is only activating logging on popup.js. Some parts are edited.

Editted

- manifest.json: permission - storage(for `chrome.storage`), activateTab(for current url), declarativeContent(for activating popup.html)
- background.js: declarativeContent is needed when activating clicking brower plugin icon. Storage logs are seen on background console.
- popup.js: `storage.local.set` is in `Logger()`. `getBackgroundPage` is changed to `chrome.tabs` for url(it access browser tabs from extension).
- popup.html: script tag for loading popup.js.

```js
//manifest.json
{
    "name": "stackTest",
    "version": "0.0.0.1",
    "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "declarativeContent", "https://*/*"],
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://*/*"],
        "js": ["contents.js"]
      }
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
      },
      "page_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
      },
    "description": "this is test.",
    "manifest_version": 2
}



//background.js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {

//declarativeContent is needed when popup should be opened
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, () => {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
            conditions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({

            })
        ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
         }])
    });

});

//load key which is logged at popup.js
chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], function(result) {
    console.log('value currently is ' + result.key);
});




//popup.js
//Start and Stop buttons for logging
const btnStart = document.getElementById("click-start");
const btnStop = document.getElementById("click-stop");

//attempt to get start/stop logging buttons to work--underwork
function Logger(isLogging) {
    console.log(isLogging)
        let logger =''
        if (isLogging){
        
        btnStart.style.display= "block";
        btnStop.style.display= "none";
        
        logger = 'logging' 

    } else {
        
        btnStart.style.display= "none";
        btnStop.style.display= "block";

        logger = 'not logging'
    }
                chrome.storage.local.set({key: logger}, function() {
    console.log('value is set to  ' + logger);

})
}
addRow();

//button to start/stop logging
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    btnStart.addEventListener("click", function() {Logger(true)}); 
    btnStop.addEventListener("click", function() {Logger(false)});
});


//using storage API to save data for last btn pressed--underwork
chrome.storage.local.set({key: Logger()}, function() {
    console.log('value is set to  ' + Logger());
});

chrome.storage.local.get(['key'], function(result) {
    console.log('value currently is ' + result.key);
});

//function to append row to HTML table 
function addRow() {
    const bg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage()   
        console.log(bg)

        // Used tabs.query for getBackgroundPage 
        // url is got from tabs.query

   // Object.keys(bg.get).forEach(function (url) {
  chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, (tabs) => {
          let url = tabs[0].url;
    //get html table
        // Append product to the table
           var table = document.getElementById("tbodyID");
            console.log('heelo')

            var arr = url.split("/");
            var protocoll = arr[0] + "//" + arr[2];

            //inputed data --
            browser= "Google Chrome";
            protocol = protocoll;
            downloads = "example";
            description = "example";
            time = Date.now();


        //put dates in array and replace it and have var as myDate
    // add new row to the table
                  //1 = in the top 
                  //table.rows.length = the end
                  //table.rows.length/2+1 = the center 

            var newRow = table.insertRow(0);

            console.log(table.rows.length)

                  // add cells to the row
                  var browserCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
                  var timeCell = newRow.insertCell(1);
                  var urlCell = newRow.insertCell(2);
                  var protocolCell = newRow.insertCell(3);
                  var downloadsCell = newRow.insertCell(4);
                  var descCell = newRow.insertCell(5);

                  // add the data to the cells

                  urlCell.innerHTML = `${url}`;
                  timeCell.innerHTML = time;
                    browserCell.innerHTML = browser;
                    descCell.innerHTML = description;
                    protocolCell.innerHTML = protocol;
                    downloadsCell.innerHTML = downloads;
                  console.log("works");
     })
            }
```

```html
<!--Start button of logging-->
    <button class="button button1" id="click-start" >
    <u> Start Logging </u>
    </button>

    <!--Stop button of logging-->
    <button class="button button2" id="click-stop">
    <u> Stop Logging </u>
    </button>

    <table class="roundedCorners" id = "tableID" border="1">
        <thead>
        <!--Example table header row with the user, url visited, and time they visited the url etc-->
            <tr>
      <!--categories-->
                <th>Browser</th>
                <th>Timestamp</th>
                <th>URL</th>
                <th>Protocol</th>
                <th>Downloaded File Names</th>
                <th>Description</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id= "tbodyID">


        </tbody>
     <!--Goal is to append to this table-->


    </table>
    <script src='./popup.js'>
    //To execute popup.js 
    </script>
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the help. I am still a bit confused though. I feel like I'm close however. Is there a way I can better chat with you to discuss my issues? I'm having trouble with the content.js file.

Comment: Should I add everything thats in popup.js to content.js. I added the addRow function to the content. The extension currently only logs the current url but I previously had it to append to the table for every url is visited, do you have an idea on what caused it to stop appending to the row. Also when the stop button is clicked it doesnt stay on the start button (which shows up after stop btn is clicked), it resets back to stop btn when i exit off popup. My full code is on https://github.com/brakiajackson/project if you are able to see what the issue may be

Comment: Happy to be helpful, @studentcs. You're almost there. I can work on with you on your github page.

Comment: @studentcs To log urls on page turns, addRow() can log urls on contents.js. On popup.js logs only alive while popup.html is opened. About stopping appending to the row, using popup.html looks good. Because when ever turning pages content.js is executed when the exetension is installed/on. For staying the start button, there may be solutions too. Using onRequest then server can send state of the buttons for a user. Or only with extensions, I heard there are ways to communicate between exetensions.

Comment: Or with using localstorage writing 'if flags', then whenever open popup.html by clicking extension plugin, the buttons are displayed on the flags.

Comment: Would be thankful if you select my answer, @studentcs!

Comment: Okay thank you, I added u to my github so you can see what im doing wrong.